# MongoRestore memory cleanup issue

Tags: mongodb, memory

MongoRestore does not clean up its temp memory uses after process is finished.

I am using mongodb version v3.4.3. on 64 bit ubuntu 16.1 machine that has 16 GB RAM.
When ever I use mongorestore, machine get start hang and all memory is being used by mongorestore. 
When mongorestore process get completes, it does not free memory.

I always restart mongod service to free memory.
Is there any memory leak in mongodb.

```
deepak@deepak-agrawal:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15974        9865         619         331        5489        5401
Swap:         29295           0       29295
deepak@deepak-agrawal:~$ sudo service mongod stop
deepak@deepak-agrawal:~$ sudo service mongod start 
deepak@deepak-agrawal:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15974        3184        7299         331        5490       12082
Swap:         29295           0       29295
```

CPU Usage and Memory Usage Summary:

```
deepak@deepak-agrawal:~$ top
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1003 mongodb   20   0 6859292 6.347g  29212 S   0.3 40.7   2:48.86 mongod
```

How to fix this issue?